# How can I find the text between a span element with no class/id using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to use Selenium to find the text between a span element that has no class, id, or anything I can think of to find it specifically.
Here is the html:
[HTML from inspect element on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT0jM.png)

I have tried the following:

```
    reqStr = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('span[data-bind*=text]')

    for i in reqStr:
        print(i.get_attribute('text'))
```

But that results in it printing just an empty list '[]'.

Any advice on how to find the text "CHEM*1040, PHYS*1130 - Must be completed prior to taking this course" is appreciated

Comment: You can search for the 3rd `<div>` (or whatever ordinal it is) and then pull all the `<span>`s from that `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could get it using a CSS Selector like:

```
reqStr = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span[data-bind="text: $data.DisplayText() + \'   \' + $data.DisplayTextExtension()"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. I actually managed to find it using:

```
    reqStr = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'*')]")
    print(reqStr)

    for i in reqStr:
        print(i.text)
```

I had this before but must have slightly messed something up because I was not getting the correct results. Thanks!